# Error 1 Could not find symbol '$'

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio

When I use Visual Studio to edit an external Javascript file and use Javascript within the page, it unsurprisingly is unaware of JQuery, because the web page that owns it hasn't loaded the Javascript file.

//test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("If you really need a code example");
});
```

As a result, I get this error:

```
Error   1   Could not find symbol '$'
```

Again, this is a design time error, not a runtime error.

Is there a way to make the Visual Studio Editor a little smarter or at least suppress these errors?

**Update:**

I think it was the Typescript editor that I was in that just complained that there was an error, no error is shown when editing the rresulting javascript file.

Modified Question:

How can I make the TypeScript file editor happy? I think the "editor" may be Web Essentials add in and that there may be a directive to make it ignore the $, perhaps. Or am I thinking of JSLint?

I''m new to all of this...

Comment: `jQuery(function($){ });`

Comment: I believe this is visual-studio, added the tag to attract visual-studio experts.

Comment: jQuery library file not visible for you project. Hence this error. Solution : Kindly check the path for the jQuery library and name of the file is case sensitive.

Comment: Error 1 Could not find symbol 'jQuery'.
As I see it, an external javascript file with no context won't know about $ or jQuery,, it's only when the web page references the js file at run time that things link up.

Comment: Please include jquery library

Comment: In TypeScript: `declare $;` or use a definition file for jQuery: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Comment: @Tarh: Thanks, but once I save this code, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
});
```

or maybe you are missing the `);` after the `}`

Comment: +1. To whoever downvoted this, please remove the downvote, as this is very likely the right answer. I always use jQuery instead of $ to avoid these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, all variables must be declared.

You can declare it with `declare var $;` at the beginning of the file.

Or you can use a definition file for jQuery:

1. [Download it](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) ;
2. Then, in your `.ts` file, include the definition file:

   /// <reference path='jquery.d.ts' />

   // here the compiler known jQuery

   $(document).ready(/* ... */);